# Spring matrix parameters

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, matrix, parameters

I have upgraded my spring version to 4.1.4 and now want to use Matrix parameters.

I have added below to enable support for matrix parameters in configuration file:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven conversion-service="applicationConversionService" enable-matrix-variables="true"/>
```

and in code I am accessing it as below in my method:

```
public ResponseEntity<String> transactions(@PathVariable("accountNumber") String accountNumber,
        @MatrixVariable(required = true,value="sinceDate") String sinceDate){....}
```

and my url is : `http://localhost:8080/spring_test/accounts/8293/transactions;sinceDate=2014-01-20;untilDate=2014-01-01;`

But I am getting `sinceDate` value as null, which is declared with `@MatrixVariable`.

Please suggest if I am missing any steps?

Thanks,
Manasi

Answer (score 0):

If you have your own `AbstractHandlerMapping` definition you should specify its `<beans:property name="removeSemicolonContent" value="false"/>`.

Otherwise I suggest you to debug the Spring code and figure out why `removeSemicolonContent` isn't reseted for the default `RequestMappingHandlerMapping`.

The break point should be in the `UrlPathHelper#removeSemicolonContent`

To make this worked you should place matrix variables in the URL just after the approriate `pathVariable`:

```
http://localhost:8080/spring_test/accounts/8293;sinceDate=2014-01-20;untilDate=‌​2014-01-01;/transactions
```

Comment: I am getting sinceDate value now when I take @PathVariable 'accountNumber' as final argument in the url. Do we need to have path variable as last argument in the request url while using matrix parameters?

Comment: Have you tried with `@MatrixVariable(pathVar = "transaction", required = true, value="sinceDate")` ? Or how is it called in your `@RequestMapping`

Comment: Yes I have tried with @MatrixVariable(pathVar="accountNumber",required=true) String accountNumber,
        @MatrixVariable(required = true,value="sinceDate") String sinceDate){....}  and @RequestMapping(value = "/accounts/{accountNumber}/transactions", method = RequestMethod.GET),].But it did not work.

Comment: No, I mean this: `@MatrixVariable(pathVar="accountNumber", required=true, value="sinceDate") String sinceDate`. Not for `accountNumber` param.

Comment: Yes I have tried above also but it does not map the request if pathVariable is in between url and not the last in the url. It gives 404 Not Found error.

Comment: Can't you do this `http://localhost:8080/spring_test/accounts/8293;sinceDate=2014-01-20;untilDate=2014-01-01;/transactions` ?

Comment: Updated my answer with that solution to be as a candidate for acceptance.